# VB.net Preview .bat files in listbox to textbox

Tags: vb.net, file, casting, directory

**How it works;** My program is finding all .bat files in folders and subfolders of a selected path.

First I have a browse button where you can select a folder. When folder is selected with browse button, I have a `inputtb1` (input textbox) that takes the full path and labels it. Finally I have a `selectbtn` (Select button) that then searches for all the bat-files and lists them in `MainListBox` (Listbox).

So to sum up, all .bat files in folder and subfolder of the specified path is listed in a listbox.

Now I have a PreviewTB (preview textbox) that are supposed to preview the content of the bat-file that is `SelectedItem` of the listbox. This is where I'm having issues.

It looks like this:

[image]

So its browse -> inputtb1 (where it says path) -> select -> mainlistbox -> then when I highlight one of the files listed, I want preview in the previewtb. An example of how how inputtb1 will look like after folder selected: `C:\Users\xxx\Google Drive`

Here is the codes for each sub (a little shortened so its faster to read)

```
**Private sub Inputtb1**
'Nothing here

**Private Sub btnBrowse_Click**
If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        Inputtb1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End If

**Private Sub btnSelect1_Click**
Dim directory = New DirectoryInfo(Inputtb1.Text)
    Dim files() As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim dirinfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Inputtb1.Text)
    files = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.bat", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each file In files
        MainListBox.Items.Add(file)
    Next


**Private Sub MainListBox_SelectedIndexChanged**        
    Dim selectedfile As String = Inputtb1.Text & MainListBox.SelectedItem
    'Check if file exists
    If System.IO.File.Exists(selectedfile) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(selectedfile)
        'Save file contents to textbox
        PreviewTB.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd
        objReader.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("File not found!")
    End If
```

**The problem:** I think is this line `Dim selectedfile As String = Inputtb1.Text & MainListBox.SelectedItem` because I can't seem to figure out how to tell the previewtb which file to open. Also if its subfolders of the path I've selected. I've tried a couple of variations, but I always get an error as soon as I highlight a .bat in the mainlistbox. The error points out the `dim selectedfile...` as I just mentioned and sais "System.InvalidCastException".

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may miss a "\" there. Take a look:

```
Inputtb1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
```

Thus it will have a format like:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Google Drive
```

And then when you do

```
Dim selectedfile As String = Inputtb1.Text & MainListBox.SelectedItem
```

Assuming `MainListBox.SelectedItem` is a `String` with value of "myfile.txt", this is what is going to be the result:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Google Drivemyfile.txt
```

Try to put additional "\"

```
Dim selectedfile As String = Inputtb1.Text + "\" + MainListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Note: and just to be sure I put additional `ToString()` there

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm! :) Only issue left is that this only works when I select files in the exact folder that is in the `inputtb1.text`. If I select files listed that are in subfolders, they won't open because "file not found" . Do you know how I can make this work? Or is it complicated, so I'd better google or ask another question...?

Comment: @MadsTheMan ah, that depends on what causes the file not found. :s I am not too sure as of now, but when you do further research, the case may get a better clarification...

Comment: Alright no worries. Im guessing it is because mainlistbox lists all files in subfolders as well, so with the path chosen as `c:\users\xxx\google drive +\+ - this will only find files within that exact path. Somehow its probably possible to make it look for the selected myfile.txt in subfolders as well. I'm going to do some research. Again, thanks. :)